# Would polymeric sand prevent weed growth in sidewalk joints for many years?

Tags: sidewalk

Has anyone successfully used polymeric sand for sidewalk joints (specifically to prevent weeds)? This is in an urban environment - this would be between the curb and the sidewalk, between sidewalk slabs, and between the sidewalk and a wall.

It seems like it could work (they are within the 1/4 inch and 1.5 inches that the instructions allow), and might hold up a long time, but I can't find anyone on the Internet talking about the long term durability of this solution, and how it holds up to weeds.

It seems like the alternative is Sikaflex style self-leveling sealant, but I've seen that fail (weeds come up) after just 3 years. I am looking (like anyone) for something that lasts a long time. Polymetric sand seems easy to install (as long as you follow the very specific instructions about watering & do it the right time of year) and is inexpensive.

Update: I am in New York City.

Comment: "Just three years" is multiple lifetimes in nature. I'm not sure it's reasonable to expect a solution to last longer than that short of installing a stainless steel plate as a walkway. Spray a mild herbicide once or twice a year and be happy.

Comment: Also, you haven't said where you are (what climate is at play). It doesn't matter how _hard_ a substance is, if there's enough expansion and contraction due to temperature that cracks develop, weeds will grow. Period. If you're in San Diego you may have better results.

Comment: Weeds will always find a way. See the book mentioned here for some in-depth contemplation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_World_Without_Us

Answer (score 2):

From the website [The Spruce](https://www.thespruce.com/what-is-polymeric-sand-2132510) comes a useful assessment to your question. Other attributes of the product are provided on the linked site, but specifically relating to weeds:

> **It deters weeds.** Weeds are amazingly resilient and can grow almost anywhere. While using polymeric sand doesn't guarantee that weeds will
> never grow in your new walkway or patio, it does help considerably.
> Ordinary sand is much more inviting than polymeric sand as a home for
> weeds.

This indicates that weeds will still appear.

Comment: I have polymeric sand between pavers in my patio and can confirm that weeds will find a way through. Definitely less weeds but still requires maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

Wherever a bit of water and soil can accumulate, weeds will grow there. Using polymeric sand will make it harder for seeds to just grow roots through the cracks, but as soon as it rains and a little bit of water with soil runoff lands in the crack, weeds will start growing.

On the other hand, there are many other methods to take care of  weeds. My favorite is just to use the string trimmer (weed wacker, whip, whatever it's called in your region) every time I do the lawn. I have more than an acre of lawn, a long driveway, pavers, sidewalk, and it only takes a few extra minutes when I do the lawn to remove the weeds from the sidewalk, driveway, pavers, etc. I would stay away from herbicides, which will contaminate the groundwater.

Comment: If your consumer-level herbicides are leaching into ground water, you're using orders of magnitude too much. Properly applied, you can replant new stuff in the same spot just 24 hours after spraying.

Comment: Thanks for your perspective. I'm reluctant to use herbicides but perhaps I need to reevaluate that (note in our case, our runoff largely goes into the ocean through our sewer system - and we don't drink local groundwater, we drink water that comes in via an extensive aqueduct system from upstate NY). I've clarified my answer. I am in NYC. This is an urban environment - it's unlikely that significant dirt will get into the cracks. There's no lawn or exposed earth near most of the sidewalk expansion joints.